# Chinese Remainder Theoram

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

How do I evaluate all the square roots of 4 mod 33 using Chinese Remainder Theoram. I know we can use mod 33 = 11 x 3. I'm not sure how to proceed to the next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried brute force?  The numbers are small enough.

$2$ is an obvious one.  To get the others, just keep adding $33$ repeatedly to $4$ and check if it's a perfect square at each step.  Upper limit (the point when you can stop) is after $32 \times 32 = 1024$.

$13$ is the next one.

Actually, because the others will be negatives mod 33, you can already tell that $-2$ and $-13$, a.k.a. $31$ and $20$, will be answers as well.  I only have to check up to $17$ for this reason (because $17 \equiv -16$ mod $33$).

So the full list is: $2, 13, 20, 31$

Answer (score 2):

The square roots of $4$ mod $p$ for $p$ a prime are clearly $\pm 2$.

You now have to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem and solve
$$
x \equiv \pm 2 \bmod 3, \quad
x \equiv \pm 2 \bmod 11
$$
You'll get four solutions mod $33$.

Comment: ... and "$\pm2 \bmod 3$" means "any number not a multiple of $3$" so the search is really quick... :-)